# Get datetime with seconds into json for a dropdown list

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime

How can I fix my code below to return a date object with the seconds? Doing a `tostring()` just return date and time to the minute.

I tried it with the ticks and it's not supported either.  This function is returning the `datetime` string for the drop down on the view so that the user can select the datetime string to filter for the search function.  Without the seconds in the datetime, the search function doesn't work correctly.

If there is another way of doing a filtered search with date also, let me know.  But, I think If I can get it to return it with the seconds; it would work fine.

```
//gets filtered list with a group by on date, 
//just want to grab unique dates by the two filtered ids
IQueryable<mylistobject> filteredlist = 
    from c in db.mylistcontext
        where(c.TypeId == TypeId && c.DeptId == deptid)
        group c by new { c.myDateTime } into grp
        select grp.FirstOrDefault();

//form the value id / name
var result = (
    from r in filteredlist
        select new {
            //id =  r.myDateTime.Ticks.ToString(), //ticks is not supported
            id =  r.myDateTime.ToString(), //the seconds is truncated
            name = r.myDateTime.ToString() // the seconds gets cut off
        }).ToList();

 return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: You can try - DateTime.Parse(string param)?

Comment: You need to return DateTime `id =  r.myDateTime,`. JsonSerializer doesn't truncate DateTime.

Comment: Specify a formatter in `ToString`

Comment: Joe - I can't specify it since it's not supported in the query.  @rnofenko I tried that too and you are right it doesn't truncate before it returns from the function but for some reason on the data return in the ajax javascript, it becomes "/Date(1432008346000)/".  I thought it could the the ticks, but it's not.  http://imgur.com/gallery/0jMboFT

Comment: So, 1. if there is a way to get a string format in the c# linq query with seconds OR decipher what /Date(143...) on the ajax side?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass dates without converting

1) ASP.NET MVC GET Action - return date as it is

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetDates()
{
    var result = new List<DateTime> {new DateTime(2013, 1, 1), new DateTime(2013, 4, 4)}
        .Select(x => new {id = x, name = x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)});
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

2) Сode on client receives dates from server and sends "id" (it's our C# DateTime) without changing

```
$.get("home/GetDates", function(dates) {
    console.log(dates);

    $.post("home/ReceiveDate", { date: dates[0].id }, function(postResult) {
        console.log(postResult);
    }, "json");
});
```

3) ASP.NET MVC POST Action - you can accept JSON date with no converting

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ReceiveDate(DateTime date)
{
    return Json(new { date }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the details answered.  I think my issue is the server side.  I need to convert the json date back again to the sql datetime so I can do a filtered search based on the date.  This seems to be my only option as I can't change the string to include the seconds except having to use the json datetime.  I am not sure your codes does that or not in (3), it's just returning a json datetime again.  I need to use the datetime in a sql server query.  Trying to find a conversion but even that proves difficult in something that should be standard.

Comment: What's the sql dateTime?

Comment: DateTime in sql: 2015-05-18 21:05:46.000 Just as long as I can convert this into a DateTime in c# with the seconds, it doesn't matter.  I tried changing my submit param to DateTime instead of String, I don't think it converts the json datetime automatically either...